# How to stop and start jms listener

Tags: java, spring, jms, listener, spring-jms

I'm using Spring and I have a JMS queue to send messages from client to server. I'd like to stop the messages from being sent when the server is down, and resend them when it's back up.

I know it was asked before but I can't make it work. I created a JmsListener and gave it an ID, but I cannot get it's container in order to stop\start it.

```
@Resource(name="testId")
private AbstractJmsListeningContainer _probeUpdatesListenerContainer;

public void testSendJms() {

    _jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue", "working");
}

@JmsListener(destination="queue", id="testId")
public void testJms(String s) {
    System.out.println("Received JMS: " + s);

}
```

The container bean is never created. I also tried getting it from the context or using @Autowired and @Qualifier("testId") with no luck.

How can I get the container?

Answer (score 1):

You need `@EnableJms` on one of your configuration classes.

You need a `jmsListenerContainerFactory` bean.

You can stop and start the containers using the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

See [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated).

Comment: I Autowired the JmsListenerEndpointRegistry and got the container from it using the ID
`_listenerContainer = _jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("listener_container_id");`

Note that the container could not be retrieved in the PostConstruct..

Answer (score 1):

If you use `CachingConnectionFactory` in your project, you need to call the `resetConnection()` method between stop and restart, otherwise the old physical connection will remain open, and it will be reused when you restart.

Answer (score 1):

I used JmsListenerEndpointRegistry. Here's my example. I hope this will help.

Bean configuration in JmsConfiguration.java. I changed default autostart option.

```
@Bean(name="someQueueScheduled")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory odsContractScheduledQueueContainerFactory() {
   DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
   ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(someActiveMQ);
   Map<String, Class<?>> typeIds = new HashMap<>();
   typeIds.put(SomeDTO);
   factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter(Collections.unmodifiableMap(typeIds)));
    factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    return factory;
}
```

Invoke in SomeFacade.java

```
public class SomeFacade {

@Autowired
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry someUpdateListener;

public void stopSomeUpdateListener() {
  MessageListenerContainer container = someUpdateListener.getListenerContainer("someUpdateListener");
  container.stop();
  }


public void startSomeUpdateListener() {
  MessageListenerContainer container = someUpdateListener.getListenerContainer("someUpdateListener");
  container.start();
  }
}
```

JmsListener implementation in SomeService.java

```
public class SomeService {

 @JmsListener(id = "someUpdateListener",
      destination = "${some.someQueueName}",
      containerFactory ="someQueueScheduled")
  public void pullUpdateSomething(SomeDTO someDTO)  {
  }
}
```